# What kind of graph/lattice problem is this?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms, coloring, recursive-algorithms

I have a problem that can be cast as:

Mark the (a?) shortest sequence of points in an $n$-dimensional positive integer lattice to reach a given target point $(t_1, t_2,...,t_n)$ from the origin (0,0,...,0), where the rules for marking a point are:

1. Pick a pivot $(p_1,...,p_n)$. In order to mark a nearest neighbour of the pivot along an axis (e.g. from the pivot (1,2,0) mark (2,2,0)), I need to have already marked at least $n$ of the $2n$ nearest neighbours (e.g. (0,2,0), (1,2,1) and (1,2,-1)).
2. We are allowed to consider the "-1 neighbours" as marked.
3. The origin (0,0,...) is marked.

In the example above we are could mark (2,2,0), (1,3,0) and (1,1,0).

We know we can slowly crawl everywhere in the lattice, but how do we go about finding the shortest sequence of marked points between the origin and any given $(t_1,...,t_n)$? Is this a sort of graph colouring problem? Is there an algorithm for this stuff?

Comment: Point $2$ seems to be quite strange, otherwise the solution would be pretty simple (just consider the sum of the absolute values of the differences $t_i-p_i$, for $i=1,2,...,n$. Anyway, as a trivial upper bound, you know that we can cover any $n$-dimensional (sub)grid as the one we need with an axis-aligned Hamiltonian path whose (Euclidean) length is equal to the absolute value of $\prod_{j=1}^{n} (p_j - t_j)$ minus $1$.

Comment: I'm, not sure I understand your upper bound. You need to pick many pivots along the way and mark among their nearest neighbours.

Comment: My English is not good enough to understand the problem (and its rules) properly, maybe. For sake of simplicity, let us assume that $p_1 < t_1, p_2 < t_2, \dots, p_n < t_n$. Then, is not sufficient to cover all the points in $[t_1 - p_1] \times [t_2 - p_2] \times \dots \times [t_n - p_n]$, starting from the point $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n)$ and ending the path in $(t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n)$?

Comment: P.S. I have read the text more carefully and I've just realized that we do not start from the point $(p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n)$, but we start from the origin (my bad!). In this case, I think that my trivial idea would work if we set $p_1=p_2=\dots=0$ (e.g., let us take the very simple $2$D case of the set ${(0,1) \times (0,1)}$ so that, if $t_1=t_2=1$, then a valid path is $(0,0)-(0,1)-(1,1)$ and its length is $2 \leq 2 \cdot 2 - 1$ returned by my upper bound.

Comment: Sure, your example in a 2x2 grid works, and your upper bound works too, but it's kind of trivial. What about (e.g.) a 100 x 100 grid? or 100 x 100 x 100 x 100 x 100 x 100 x 100 x 100 grid? What I'm after is a method to find the *shortest* sequence of marked points in an N-dim lattice and the target may be far away from the origin.